# I have to remove set of duplicate words in the given string using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

For Eg:-

I have to scrape address from multiple websites. Sometimes address having repeated country name or address.

```
$string1="No 3, 3rd street mumbai india 3rd street";
$string2="#3 1019 GM Amsterdam Funda Real Estate BV 1019 GM Amsterdam The Netherlands";
```

I need to remove the group of n number of words in the given string.
In the given 
$string1 contains "3rd street" as duplicate. I need to remove.
$string2 contains "1019 GM Amsterdam" as duplicate.

Output will be..

```
$string1="No 3, 3rd street mumbai india";
$string2="#3 1019 GM Amsterdam Funda Real Estate BV The Netherlands";
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output `$string1` be `"aaa bbb ccc"`?

Comment: How that `n` (of _"the group of n number of words"_) is defined? If it is not fixed, in what range in varies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with some brute force method try the following

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX;

my $string1="aaa bbb aaa ccc aaa bbb";
#my $string1="fff ggg hhh ddd jjj fff ggg hhh";
#my $string2 = "fff ggg hhh ddd jjj fff ggg hhh fff ggg mmm";

my $string1_count = () = $string1=~m/\s+/g;
my $string_divide = ceil($string1_count/2);

for(my $i = $string_divide; $i > 1; $i--)
{
    last if($string1 =~s/((?:\w+\s?){$i}).+\K\1//g);
}


print "$string1\n";
```

Comment: Hi, It is working for the given string, i am testing with some other string like "fff ggg hhh ddd jjj fff ggg hhh fff ggg mmm" it showing "fff ggg hhh ddd jjj   mmm", but i need "fff ggg hhh ddd jjj fff ggg mmm". is that possible?

Comment: @Senthil Are you telling you want to exit the loop in the first match. Post edited check it.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
my $string1="aaa bbb aaa ccc aaa bbb";
my $string2="fff ggg hhh ddd jjj fff ggg hhh";

my @split = split / /, $string1;
my @unique = keys {map {$_ => 1} @split};

my $string3 = join " ", sort @unique;

print $string3;
```

Comment: [Starting with Perl 5.14, an experimental feature allowed keys to take a scalar expression. This experiment has been deemed unsuccessful, and was removed as of Perl 5.24.](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)

Comment: @Сухой27. Thanks for your information. We will check hence I am working with 5.18 only.

Comment: If i run this code, it will give the ouput "aaa bbb ccc". But i need is "aaa bbb aaa ccc".

Comment: please make sure on this since there is a lack of logic instead